# How to Unit Test a ViewModel using Flows and LiveData with runTest?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

Imagine my ViewModel looks like this :

```kotlin
class ViewModelA(
    repository: Repository,
    ioCoroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) : ViewModel() {
    val liveData : LiveData<String> = repository.getFooBarFlow().asLiveData(ioCoroutineDispatcher)
}
```

Imagine my Repository implementation looks like this :

```kotlin
class RepositoryImpl : Repository() {
    override fun getFooBarFlow() : Flow<String> = flow {
        emit("foo")
        delay(300)
        emit("bar")
    }
}
```

How could I unit test the fact that "foo" is emitted **immediately** by the `LiveData`, then **300ms later (no more, no less)**, that "bar" is emitted by the `LiveData` ?

You can use JUnit 4 or 5, but you have to use **Kotlin 1.6**, **kotlinx-coroutines-test 1.6** and `runTest {}` instead of `runBlockingTest {}` (I have no issues testing with `runBlockingTest {}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `TestCoroutineRule` in coroutine-test 1.6 looks like this :

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class TestCoroutineRule : TestRule {

    val testCoroutineDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description?) = object : Statement() {
        @Throws(Throwable::class)
        override fun evaluate() {
            Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)

            base.evaluate()

            Dispatchers.resetMain()
        }
    }

    fun runTest(block: suspend TestScope.() -> Unit) = testScope.runTest { block() }
}
```

`runTest` behave a lot more differently than `runBlockingTest` :

> runTest() will automatically skip calls to delay() and handle uncaught exceptions. Unlike runBlockingTest(), it will wait for asynchronous callbacks to handle situations where some code runs in dispatchers that are not integrated with the test module. ([source](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/introducing-kotlinx-coroutines-1-6-0/#kotlinx-coroutines-test-update))

Take note, `advanceTimeBy(n)` **doesn't really advance the virtual coroutine time by n**. The difference with the 1.5 version is **it won't execute tasks scheduled at n, only tasks scheduled at n - 1**. To execute tasks schedule **at** n, you need to use the new function `runCurrent()`.

An example implementation for the test would be :

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class DetailViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Test
    fun getFooBarFlow() = testCoroutineRule.runTest {
        // Given
        val fakeRepository = object : Repository {
            override fun getFooBarFlow(): Flow<String> = flow {
                emit("foo")
                delay(300)
                emit("bar")
            }
        }

        // When
        val liveData = ViewModelA(fakeRepository, testCoroutineRule.testCoroutineDispatcher).liveData
        liveData.observeForever { }

        // Then
        runCurrent()
        assertEquals("foo", liveData.value)

        advanceTimeBy(300)
        runCurrent()
        assertEquals("bar", liveData.value)
    }
}
```

A complete implementation with some helpers can be found here : https://github.com/NinoDLC/HiltNavArgsDemo/commit/c2d84dd79c846b96d419217eb68dd7e12baedeb6